# Redmine project unit test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have added a custom plugin to `Redmine 3.2.1` and that plugin has introduced a new mandatory field `project_type` of string type, which can either be `internal`, `partner` or `external`.

Now when I run `project_test` file,

```
ruby test/unit/project_test.rb
```

I am getting following error messages,

> ProjectTest#test_#rolled_up_versions_should_include_versions_for_a_subproject:
>   ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Project type cannot be blank
>       test/object_helpers.rb:38:in `generate!'
>       test/unit/project_test.rb:495:in`block in '

What's the standard way to update `projects` fixtures, so that i can include `project_type` in it?